# Why does software center prompt for updates after ap-get update?

Tags: apt, updates

So after any installation I'll firstly execute: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`, but why does the software center still pop-up after the updates were ran with the ctl, with additional updates?
Are there some updates that I cannot download by the terminal or does anybody have an explanation for this?

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get upgrade` doesn't do a full upgrade. It will only upgrade existing packages and won't do anything that involves installing new packages or removing old ones, both of which are often required for a full upgrade.

It's these other updates that Update Manager wants to apply.

I would just never use `apt-get upgrade` and always use `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

I also wouldn't pass in `-y`. Given what I've just said about `apt update`, that's probably safe, but `apt dist-upgrade` could do harm if you've done something silly beforehand. Always check to make sure Apt isn't going to do something silly. It takes seconds and saves hours.